# what do these characters mean?

Tags: translation

[image]

I got this box at an antique shop and it has these characters on it, could anyone translate?

Comment: It looks like "花卉" - "flowers and plants".

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @r13 looks like one of the variant forms 芲 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8A%B2 or https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%B0%B0%A8